# Why I can set private field in playground

Tags: swift, swift2

I have a simple `Vehicle` class which has a **private** field named `_odometer`, then, I have a computed-property named `odometer`(it has setter & getter).

I think `_odometer` should not be able to set since it is a **private** field, but in playground, it can be set, why? Here is my code in play ground:

[image]

As you can see, I created an instance of `Vehicle` named `volvo`. By default `_odometer` is 500, but I can directly set `_odometer` to **0** on `volvo`, when print out the 'odometer', it is **0**. **WHY** I can set private field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift `private` is slightly semantically different than in other OO languages, it is private to the source file.

In [Swift Access Control](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html):

> Private access restricts the use of an entity to its own defining
>   source file. Use private access to hide the implementation details of
>   a specific piece of functionality.

Comment: In Swift4 a new access control was introduced: `fileprivate` which now has the properties you described. `private` now works as expected from other languages