# Swift access control on computed properties: why does this work?

Tags: swift, class-visibility

I seem to be misunderstanding something about access control modifiers in Swift. Here is my code from a playground:

```
class Something {
    private (set) var name :String {
    get { return "" }
    set {}
    }
}
var thing = Something();
thing.name = "";
```

My intuition and experience from other languages tells me that there should be a compiler error on the last line.

The book I'm learning from however states that private means the member being modified is only accessible from the same source file.

Am I safe to assume this scenario would generally be an error in most projects, and this is only because I'm running this code in a playground?

Is the statement that private members can only be accessed from the same source file totally accurate?

Comment: *"private members can only be accessed from the same source"* is totally accurate for Swift 2. –  Swift 3 (Xcode 8 beta 6) changed the meaning of private, compare [What is a good example to differentiate between fileprivate and private in swift3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39027250/what-is-a-good-example-to-differentiate-between-fileprivate-and-private-in-swift).

Comment: @MartinR Thank you, post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I don't want to repeat existing answers :) – And actually your question is unclear to me. Your last statement is correct, so why do you wonder about it? What do you mean by " this scenario would generally be an error in most projects"?

Comment: Also possible duplicate of [Why I can set private field in playground](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35379133/why-i-can-set-private-field-in-playground) or [Private var is accesible from outside the class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26087447/private-var-is-accesible-from-outside-the-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rule is valid for all versions of Swift 2. It is valid for your example as well, and worked because your setter code is in the same file (if I understand your example correctly) in which the setter was invoked.

The top-level assignment expression `thing.name = "";` was allowed because it is running in a playground. Outside playgrounds, this particular top-level assignment would be illegal in **most cases** (there *are* exceptions!).

---

Bonus explanation of what constitutes as "top-level code" and where it is applicable; from the official Swift blog [here](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=7):

> However, top-level code is not allowed in most of your Swift source
>   files. For clarity, any executable statement not written within a
>   function body, within a class, or otherwise encapsulated is considered
>   top-level. We have this rule because if top-level code were allowed in
>   all your files, it would be hard to determine where to start the
>   program.

...

> You’ll notice that earlier we said top-level code isn’t allowed in
>   most of your app’s source files. The exception is a special file named
>   “main.swift”, which behaves much like a playground file, but is built
>   with your app’s source code. The “main.swift” file can contain
>   top-level code, and the order-dependent rules apply as well. In
>   effect, the first line of code to run in “main.swift” is implicitly
>   defined as the main entrypoint for the program. This allows the
>   minimal Swift program to be a single line — as long as that line is in
>   “main.swift”.

Comment: @MartinR: You're right. I've updated my answer, hopefully this edit should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

> The book I'm learning from however states that private means the member being modified is only accessible **from the same source file.**

And your example is accessing it from the same source file. What's the issue?

In Swift 3, `private` becomes `fileprivate`, wherein access is allowed anywhere from the same file. `private` in Swift 3 has the behavior you expect, where access is only allowed within the class/struct/enum itself.